# Duplicate entry on toc when using lstlistoflistings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

Hi i am making my thesis on latex and i have write some code examples using the `lstlisting` package. 
Then i have used the command `\lstlistoflistings` to add all the example at the beginning of my thesis but on the `toc` i have another entry with the name `contents`.
[image]
In the main.tex of my thesis i have `renew` some commands to change the text in Italian. Here there is the code:
       \documentclass[11pt, oneside]{Thesis} % The default font size and one-sided printing (no margin offsets)

```
   \usepackage[square, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
   \usepackage{csvsimple}
   \usepackage{listing}
   \usepackage{listings}
   \usepackage{color}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \usepackage{wrapfig}

   \renewcommand\contentsname{Contenuti}
   \lhead{\emph{Contenuti}} 
   % Set the left side page header to "Contents"
   \tableofcontents % Write out the Table of Contents

   \renewcommand\listfigurename{Lista delle Figure}
   \lhead{\emph{Lista delle Figure}} 
   % Set the left side page header to "List of Figures"
   \listoffigures % Write out the List of Figures

   \renewcommand\listtablename{Lista degli Tabelle}
   \lhead{\emph{Lista delle Tabelle}} 
   % Set the left side page header to "List    of Tables" 
   \listoftables % Write out the List of Tables

   \renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Lista degli Esempi}
   \lhead{\emph{Lista degli Esempi}}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}
   \lstlistoflistings
```

How can i remove the highlited content entry from my toc?

Complete code Here : https://www.overleaf.com/2099409mzswhq#/5337501/

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Why aren't you using `babel`? In Italian it's much preferred to say “Indice”, not “Contenuti” and “Elenco delle tabelle” rather than “Lista”. Why loading both `listing` and `listings`?

Comment: We will still need to see some compilable code to reproduce the behaviour and propose a fix.  As @egreg mentioned, using `\usepackage[italian]{babel}` is much preferred and would have saved you some time.

Comment: Do not put font switches in elements like `lhead`. Use a consistent interface for your document and define it globally using `\itshape`. `emph` would be wrong here.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, I have included `\usepackage[italian]{babel}` but still remains the English word on `toc`.

Comment: @Johannes_B How can I use `\itshape` for `\lhead` command?

Comment: `lhead{\itshape \leftmark}` set globally, i.e. once. You are doing stuff by hand right now, which is very error prone.

Comment: Please give us a link to your `Thesis.cls` file

Comment: @karlkoeller https://web.archive.org/web/20140911175029/http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Thesis-Template.zip

Comment: I don't get "Contents" in the ToC compiling your code with your `Thesis.cls`, but probably you have something in your inputed files.

Comment: I have tried upload the project in https://www.overleaf.com/ and https://www.papeeria.com/landing but there the same bug. I have cleaned up all generated files keeping only the sources. But there's still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:
Copy the original `Thesis.cls` froms the original template as @Jonas Nyrup posted and replace the one on my actual project.
Then I have re-configure it, adjusting some commands(on this template you have to fill the data about you University and stuff).

Original Template : https://web.archive.org/web/20140911175029/http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Thesis-Template.zip

My thesis : https://www.overleaf.com/2099409mzswhq

Comment: Seems like you solved your problem. Would you like to give us more informations about how did you re-configure it? Otherwise this post is considered to be a "SOLVED"-mark but not an "answer".

Comment: Hope the answer now is clear

Comment: I had the same problem but didn't find the solution here. I don't know what "reconfiguration" actually means. A diff of both files only gives me minor changes regarding the institution, author names etc. A workaround for the "two-entries-bug" is the following: https://gist.github.com/miho/a7f54e70fae82f78076675619fde7eb6 Unfortunately, it's only a hack. Still looking for a real fix.